# Teamstudio XControl: Is there a function or a property in FormViewer that allows deleting of documents?

Tags: xpages, xpages-ssjs, teamstudio-unplugged

I'm a bit new in Teamstudio xcontrol ( a bootcard based UI for xpage ) and i'm wondering if there is a property or a function that allows deleting of documents. I checked the FormViewer Custom control, FormEditor and any custom control that is related to domino documents or view but I haven't found any. I also checked the website of the xcontrol but I haven't found any. Do I miss something or do we really need to create the functionality on our own. Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They're isn't, however in the upcoming version 1.2 we do support the addition of custom buttons so you could add your own delete button.

Comment: Hmm that clears my head. Thanks for the heads up. So when will the next version be released? Any tentative dates?

Comment: It's being tested at the moment so I'd hope in the next week.

Comment: Yes! Thank you very much for the information. I'll look forward into it.